# Manage Location of Component in one of the pane in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I am new in SWING. I just started learning about `JSplitPane`. I tried to find answer almost everywhere and I ended up with nothing.

My Question is how to use `setBound(int,int,int,int)` method for the component which resides within one of the pane(left pane or right pane). Ultimately I want to set location of component in individual pane.

How can I do it?

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. `I am new in SWING` - keep a link to the tutorial handy for all the Swing basics.

Comment: thanks...link is useful - @camickr